# Disable the back,recent apps button , power button, home and home long press button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Before asking this question I tried the many solutions related to this topic on StackOverflow but some solutions are confusing and some solutions are not working may be an android version issue.

Therefore, I asked this question so please help me to **Disable the back, recent apps button, power button, home and home long press button** when the activity launched.

The answer should work in **android 4.4.x to above version**.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. User should always have a way to get out of any app, or shut down his/her device no matter where he/she is.

Comment: @Fustigador I agree with you but some apps need this feature like `SpinMe alarm clock` that use this feature to force the user to wake up.

Comment: Maybe...but if there is a way, will not be an easy one.

Comment: for what i know ,only back button can be handled.

Comment: How did you solve this, please update the answer if you figured it out.

Comment: Wrote an App for test reasons that could handle all Buttons and started in Boot. Don't do that. You won't get out unless you uninstall it again in safe-mode

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried onBackPressed() function?

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
         // code here to show dialog
         super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
    }
```

The `onBackPressed()` function is called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key.
    [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
I am using this to disable back press button on Activity.

For Other like power button press, you can try below code.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // do what you want with the power button
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

OR

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivitySetupMenu.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

You need to find out Android KeyEvent.
[KeyEvent.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: what about the others??